# Navision 5.0 number series from stored procedure

Tags: sql, .net, navision

Is there any chance to get the number series value from stored procedure? I'm trying to integrate with Navision 5.0 using sql tables. Maybe the number series is stored in some sql table? Or there is some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number series are stored in tables `No. Series` and `No. Series Line.` In line table you can find last used number for each series. To get nex number you would have to implement the same function as Nav built-in `IncStr`.

Next you lock line table. Get last used number. Increase it. Use it as you like. Save it to line table so it wouldn't be used by Nav. That's it.